# AS3 - Creating Objects in a for loop AND naming them

Tags: object, for-loop

Here is what I am doing basically.

```
 var Player1:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};//etc... I need each Player to have the same set of properties.
 var Player2:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};
 var Player3:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};
 var Player3:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};
```

Now, I have a LOT more properties in each object, and I am creating them all dynamically through for loops and arrays. So each object will have a random name, age, etc...
I hate that I have to write the same line of code over and over, the only thing changing is the number at the end of the word Player.

What I want is...

```
createPlayers(4);
function createPlayers(a){
for(var i=1;i<a;i++){
var thisPlayer = "Player" + i;
thisPlayer:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};
}
```

Now, of course I cannot reference them because the var thisPlayer was created in the function.

I also tried:

```
Players:Object = {age:Number,playerName:String};
Player1:Players = new Players //OR
Player1:Object = new Players //ETC...
```

I am missing something here.

I want to assign a "Player1" Object to a "P1" var so the btnP1 can call upon it.

```
case btnP1:txt_name.text = P1.playerName;
case btnP2:txt_name.text = P2.playerName; //etc...
```

Comment: Thank you all in advance. I realize the answer is out there already, but I have TRIED so hard, and never find an answer that gets through to me, or works in my situation.

Comment: Could your put the players you are creating into an array, and so you'd basically do something like `var a = []; a.push({age:21, playerName:"Name"});` ? You could also use specific indices instead of just pushing, if you want to preserve an order. This also fits better with you `createPlayers(int)` function, which seems to want to return something...just return the array!

Comment: To get info, you'd do something like `txt_name.text = a[0].playerName`

Comment: Interesting. I never thought to use Arrays. Let me try this out and get back at ya. Thanks.

Comment: I'll keep at it, but It gets confusing fast. Like I said though, I will keep at it. I love arrays, and this is a good exercise. If anyone else can help with this with 'Objects" instead of Arrays, I would appreciate it.The more you know... rainbow.